Can you use LXC containers with full desktop Linux guests (just like VMs) on Fedora Workstation?
I would like to sandbox a complete desktop linux installation on a Linux host and have graphical hardware acceleration in the guest.
To my knowledge; technologies like SR-IOV that would allow this ability in virtual machines is not yet supported for consumer graphics cards and I don't have a second (or onboard) GPU to do PCI passthrough (plus don't want to go through the crazy setup needed for attaching/detaching with kvm).
I dabbled with Proxmox and saw that LXC containers - which share the host hardware - can be installed with full desktop GUIs and be used in the same way virtual machines can be used.
I would love to have this capability on my workstation PC running Fedora but I haven't found a way to do this with existing virtual machine GUIs.
Is there a GUI frontend for managing Linux containers that are able to run complete distros?
